# Unexpected switch command behavior in TCL

Tags: switch-statement, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to run the below switch block using TCL. I am expecting the output to be **10** based on how the switch statement works. But the output comes out to be **Default**. I am not what's the explanation behind that and how I can fix it.

```
set a 10
set data 10

switch $data {
    $a {
        puts "10"
    }
    default {
        puts "Default"
    }
}
```

The output is:

> Default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tcl, the string enclosed in {} is literal. The variables in the string is not substituted. The same rule applies to the statements of the {} blocks passed to if/for/switch commands.

So in your case, $a is a literal string, not 10, for the switch command.

You may re-write your switch block as following thus $a is substituted to 10 before passed to switch command.

```
switch $data [list \
    $a {
        puts "10"
    } \
    default {
        puts "Default"
    } \
]
```

Comment: Or even omit the `list` enclosure: switch can take one argument after the string or it can take an even number of arguments: `switch $data $a {puts 10} default {puts default}` (with backslash+newlines as needed)